# Making push button visible in maingui after clicking close push button in subgui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I have a main gui with 2 pushbuttons. The first button opens a subgui and the other button is the "run" pushbutton which is `'Enable'=Off`. It's grey and not clickable. I know I can turn the enable "on" with this command: `set(handles.start_pushbutton,'Enable','on');`
I execute this command in the subgui by clicking the "Close" button.

```
function pushbutton_Beenden_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
closereq;
set(handles.start_pushbutton,'Enable','on');
```

How can I tell him to set the command but in the main gui?

> Error: Reference to non-existent field 'start_pushbutton'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `start_pushbutton` is defined in the *main* GUI, it is not available in the `handles` structure of your sub GUI. You'll want to either store a handle to your main GUI within your sub GUI's `handles` struct .

```
% From within your main GUI
hfig = subGUI();

% Add the (current) main GUI handle to the subGUI handles
handles = guidata(hfig);

handles.parentGUI = hObject;
guidata(hfig, handles);
```

Then from within the subGUI callback:

```
% Get the GUIDATA from the parent GUI
parentdata = guidata(handles.parentGUI);

% Change the pushbutton property
set(parentdata.start_pushbutton, 'Enable', 'on');
```

Or you can use a `Tag` on the `uicontrol` so that you can find it from the other GUI.

```
% From the GUI that has this button
uicontrol('Tag', 'MyPushButton')

% From the button that was defined in the parent GUI
button = findall(0, 'Tag', 'MyPushButton');
set(button, 'Enable', 'on')
```